# Why Curly Brackets behave differently in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

As far as I know, Javascript follows ECMA specification and according to that,

```
var x=[2,3,4] // represents array
```

and

```
var y= {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3} // represents object with key/value pair
```

But I am confused because of below 2 examples:

**Example 1:**

```
{"a","b","c"} // Is valid with return type --> "c"
```

whereas

**Example 2:**

```
var x={"a","b","c"} // Is Invalid
```

Can someone please explain reason of outcomes for last 2 examples ?

Comment: Example 1 is a statement block, example 2 is an incorrect object initializer.

Comment: Your Example 1 doesn't *return* `c`, but `c` will be logged in the console if you paste Example 1 into the console, because `c` is the last expression evaluated

Comment: @prasanth That's not a dup. The question here is about using `{}` when *not* declaring any variable.

Comment: I recommend searching "comma operator" to learn more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curly braces are used for two things in JavaScript.

1. Delimiters around object literals, as in `var y= {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}`
2. Delimiters around statement blocks, as in `if (y) { x = 1; z = 2; }`

If the `{` is at the beginning of a statement, then it's treated as the second type, so it's parsed as a statement block. That's what your Example 2 is. The statement is the expression `"a","b","c"`. This statement uses the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), so its value is the last expression, which is `"c"`. In a function you'd need to use `return` to return that value, but when you type a statement in the JavaScript console, it's automatically evaluated and the value is printed.

Example 2 is type 1, but the syntax of the object contents is invalid, so you get an error.

Comment: Thanks for clearing things. Can you please provide me link of these 2 definitions in official document?

Answer (score 0):

When using `{}` only without assigning in a variable is just evaluating expressions, as others have stated in the comments above. That is why it will log the last expression evaluated. In the second case, it is an incorrect object initialization. The possiblle scenarios are:

```
var x = {"a","b","c"}; //Invalid as object properties incorrectly defined.
var y = ["a","b","c"]; // Correct if you want an array with these elements.
var z = {
   a: "some value",
   b: "some value",
   c: "some value"
};  // Also correct if you want a,b,c as properties of an object.
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your `var test = ` object...  It's perfectly valid.  Keys can be quoted, and must be quoted in some cases.

Comment: I know it works, but I am a bit confused with the convention, will edit my answer. I will have to look into why keys must be quoted in different scenarios. Thanks.